# How to install DevExpress Grid for Xamarin in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

This is obviously an idiotic question:

It appears that DevExpress Grid would be the perfect solution to a problem I'm having with a cross-platform app in Xamarin Forms on Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 x64.

However, I cannot find this component on NuGet. Also, I have downloaded the DevExpress Grid but I have no idea how to install it.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Via Components : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xamarin/CustomDocument12301 They also now have non-design mode Nugets for your build server: https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2017/03/30/devexpress-nuget-preview-release-get-your-key.aspx

Comment: Thanks! You clarified it perfectly.

Comment: The component on the Xamarin Store is 17.1.2.0 and does not seem to include the "Shared Project" compatible assemblies which they reference in their documentation. Any idea where the 17.2.4.0 version can be downloaded?

Comment: I think @SushiHangover's comment should move to answer so that people can view that this is proper and selected answer, i have just used `DexExpress Grid for Xamarin Forms` with `NuGet`